# Do web spiders read content that is not shown with display none?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, bots

As the title says: Do web spiders read content that is not shown with `display: none;` CSS code?

I have visited my website with Lynx, and I can still see the content.

Comment: I would assume if its on the page, the spider will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Some search engine spiders supposedly don't index it or only use it to check for spam, but it is visible. Most spiders don't process CSS or client side scripting.